# Div class equivilent for Angular-Formly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-formly

we have recently discovered AngularFormly.  It seems like an awesome way to reduce form creation time and the mind numbing maintenance that normally comes with forms.

I have been doing a little bit of research and I cannot find a good example if the following is possible...

Say that I currently have a form where each label/inputfield is wrapped in a `div` with a particular class.  This class handles all of the formatting/aligning/etc on the page.  This class is part of our company's standard layout and thus it must be used.

Is there a way to include something like this for each item within a `fields` array for Formly?

Div example (I want to recreate the `form__section` class):

```
<div class="form__section">
    <label id="Label10" class="form__label">Relationship</label>
    <div class="form__input--small">
    <select name="relationship" required type="number" ng-model="con.Relationship" style="width: 150px" ng-options="option.Value for option in relationships">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi, if I understand you want to embed/wrap all your formly controls into a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create what I was looking for using wrappers.  I then added the wrappers to the various types that I created.